# Неправильно работает Шифр Цезаря

Tags: python, математика, шифрование, физика

Нужна помощь! Что-то не так
Получаю 'Sello my little friends!'
А должно быть
Hello my little friends!' -> 'Spwwz xj wteewp qctpyod!' offset=37

```
message = input("Введите сообщение: ")
offset = int(input("Введите сдвиг: "))
encoded_message = ""
for ch in message:
    ch_index = ord(ch)
    if ch_index <= 122 and ch_index >= 97 or ch_index <=90 and ch_index >= 65:
        # найти положение в 0-26
        print("Before:",ch_index)
        ch_index = ord(ch) - ord("a")
        print("After", ch_index)
        # выполнить перестановку
        ch_index = (ch_index + offset) % 26
        print("Change", ch_index)
        # преобразовать в новый символ
        new_char = chr(ch_index + ord("a"))
        print('new_ASCII:', new_char)
        # добавление к зашифрованной строке
        encoded_message += new_char
        print("ENCODED", encoded_message)
    else:
        encoded_message += ch
   
        
print(message)
print(encoded_message)
print(offset)
```

Comment: if ch.isupper() or ch.lower(): - здесь ошибка!

Comment: Т.е. даже примитивными средствами отладки не воспользовался, сразу побежал за помощью? Кстати, то, что написано в вопросе на соответствует результату, который даёт этот код.

Comment: Я прохожу курс и там типо уже свой пайтон интерпретатор я его запустил но вот такую ошибка выдало.Запускал на Айдл все ок

Comment: Кажется я понял можно сделать через позиции тоби сравнивать ch_index

Comment: if ch_index <= 122 and ch_index >= 97 проверю.Немного переделать код нужно

Comment: Я переделал все работает все ок но один символ H  не меняется...Почему?***

Comment: Потому что у "H" другой ASCII код, из-за чего буква не проходит вашу проверку и записывается как есть.  Под проверку `ch_index <= 122 and ch_index >= 97` подходят только строчные буквы.

Comment: УРА все получилось

Answer (score 1):

вот тебе не большой пример может пригодиться

```
print('Шифр Цезаря')

lang = input('Выберете язык. Русский или английский. Введите ru или en: ')
direction = input('Что вы ходите сделать? Шифрование или дешифрование? Введите cipher или decipher: ')
if direction == 'decipher':
    question = input('Вы знаете шаг сдвига? yes или no: ')
    if question == 'yes':
        step = input('Введите шаг сдвига: ')
else:
    step = input('Введите шаг сдвига: ')
original_text = input('Введите текст: ')

ru_alphabet = 'абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'  # 32 буквы (0-31)
en_alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  # 26 букв (0-25)
symbols = '1234567890 .,?"!\'-'

# Алгоритм шифрования
def ceasar_cipher(text, alphabet, step):
    result_text = []
    for letter in text:
        steps = alphabet.find(letter.lower()) + int(step)  # Находим сдвиг буквы
        if letter in symbols:  # Если есть символы оставляем без изменений
            result_text.append(letter)
            continue
        elif steps < len(alphabet):  # Если шаг в пределах индексов списка алфатвитов
            if steps < 0:  # Действия при расшифровки
                if lang == 'en':
                    steps += 26
                else:
                    steps += 32
            if letter == letter.upper():  # Если была прописная буква, то новая будет в том же регистре
                ch_letter = alphabet[steps]
                result_text.append(ch_letter.upper())
            else:
                ch_letter = alphabet[steps]
                result_text.append(ch_letter)
        elif steps >= len(alphabet):  # Если шаг вышел за пределы индексов списка алфатвитов
            if letter == letter.upper():
                ch_letter = alphabet[steps - len(alphabet)]
                result_text.append(ch_letter.upper())
            else:
                ch_letter = alphabet[steps - len(alphabet)]
                result_text.append(ch_letter)
    result_text = ''.join(result_text) 
    return result_text 


def is_valid_input(direction, lang):
    if direction == 'cipher' or direction == 'decipher':
        if lang == 'ru' or lang == 'en':
            return True
    else:
        return False


if is_valid_input(direction, lang):
    if direction == 'cipher':
        if lang == 'en':
            print(ceasar_cipher(original_text, en_alphabet, step))
        else:
            print(ceasar_cipher(original_text, ru_alphabet, step))
    elif direction == 'decipher':
        if lang == 'en':
            if question == 'yes':
                print(ceasar_cipher(original_text, en_alphabet, -(int(step))))
            else:
                for i in range(len(en_alphabet)):
                    print('Вариант', i, ceasar_cipher(original_text, en_alphabet, i))
        elif lang == 'ru':
            if question == 'yes':
                print(ceasar_cipher(original_text, ru_alphabet, -(int(step))))
            else:
                for i in range(len(ru_alphabet)):
                    print('Вариант', i, ceasar_cipher(original_text, ru_alphabet, i))                          
else:
    print('Вы ошиблись в вводе, повторите попытку')
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно.Я такие коды видел в интернете да. Но мой пока что более примитивный и упрощенный

Comment: @Alduin , ты просто сравни как проходит сдвиг и думаю поймёшь